# Re-projecting a SpatialPointsDataFrame does not change the extent

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp, rgdal

I'm trying to overlay data related to bat locations (SpatialPointsDataFrame) on to the state of Colorado (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame). The CRS of the two objects are different:

```
crs(colorado)
#CRS arguments:
# +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
crs(BatRange_data)
#CRS arguments:
# +proj=utm +zone=13 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

When I reproject the bat data, the CRS does indeed change, but the extent is unaffected.

**Before:**

```
BatRange_data
#class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
#features    : 2456 
#extent      : 139996.3, 748812, 4094998, 4535103  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=13 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#variables   : 17
```

**After:**

```
geo_proj = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
crs(BatRange_data) = geo_proj

BatRange_trnsfrmd = spTransform(BatRange_data,geo_proj)
BatRange_trnsfrmd
#class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
#features    : 2456 
#extent      : 139996.3, 748812, 4094998, 4535103  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#variables   : 17
```

I can't plot the points on the polygon, as the extent of my polygon object is dissimilar to that of my points object:

```
colorado
#class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : -109.0608, -102.042, 36.99223, 41.00561  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#variables   : 13
```

Why is the extent of the SpatialPointsDataFrame not changing when re-projected and transformed?

**Reproducible example**(I tested this myself, and sent it to a friend; it IS reproducible with what is provided):

```
#Libraries
x = c('raster','sp','rgdal')

# If you don't know if you've installed the packages for some of these 
# libraries, run this:
# install.packages(x)

lapply(x, library, character.only=TRUE)
rm(x)

# Read in and format data -------------------------------------------------
BatRange_data = new("SpatialPoints", coords = structure(c(179935.719907205, 179935.938979813, 179935.938979813, 176598.335967664, 176598.335967664, 4499963.43180688, 4499963.30060606, 4499963.30060606, 4489332.4211975, 4489332.4211975), .Dim = c(5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(176598.335967664, 4489332.4211975, 179935.938979813, 4499963.43180688), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"))) , proj4string = new("CRS"    , projargs = NA_character_))

#Use state bounds from gadm website:
us = getData("GADM", country="USA", level=1)

#Extract states (need to uppercase everything)
co = "Colorado" 

colorado = us[match(toupper(co),toupper(us$NAME_1)),]

#Re-project bat data to 'longlat'
geo_proj = 
  "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
crs(BatRange_data) = geo_proj

BatRange_trnsfrmd =
  spTransform(BatRange_data,geo_proj)

plot(BatRange_trnsfrmd)
plot(colorado,add=TRUE)
```

Comment: The example is not reproducible to us, as it depends on "Armstrong_Edited"; and needlessly complicated loading about 30 libraries, while three would suffice. (or two: `library(raster); library(rgdal)`)

Comment: "Armstrong_Edited" is used to make `BatRange_data`, for which I include the `dput` output at the end. So, this IS reproducible for you. 

If you don't want to load all the libraries, then delete the one's you don't want. It takes seconds to load, so it's not exactly "complicated".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
geo_proj = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
crs(BatRange_data) = geo_proj

BatRange_trnsfrmd = spTransform(BatRange_data,geo_proj)
BatRange_trnsfrmd
```

you are overwriting the original projection of `BatRange_data` to lat/long **before** trying to reproject it. `spTransform` therefore is doing nothing, since it's trying to reproject from epsg:4326 to epsg:4326. This is why your extent is not changing.

You should therefore probably just remove this line:

`crs(BatRange_data) = geo_proj`

and all should work.

HTH.